# How to request from multiple sources with urllib.request.Request?

Tags: python-3.4

The following code makes a single request to Yahoo API. How do I manage to request from multiple sources using `urllib.request.Request`? I am aware of [gerequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests). If possible, Is there any performance difference between the two?

*Any suitable modules on this topic?*

```
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, }

    assembled_request = urllib.request.Request(YAHOO, None, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(assembled_request)
    html_data = response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "bundle" multiple requests into one, the overhead needed to generate the request object on the client should be trivial anyway. You are pretty much just waiting for the request to go through and for the server to respond. If you need to send requests in bulk, doing it asynchronously is the best way.

If you are using an API on the web to query some data, there is often some equivalent of a get_multiple() method that you can use instead of just using get() X amount of times. This might be the kind of thing you are looking for.

For example:

```
www.example.com/get_cat.html?brown=1
```

Might yield a brown cat object.

While:

```
www.example.com/get_cats.html?brown=1
```

Might yield all the brown cat objects that the database contains.

These kinds of methods save time and bandwidth for both the server and client.